# how derivative gain in PD controller influences tracking error

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

1. List item

For a proportional and derivative feedback control, the the response and tracking error in frequency domain can be represented as

$Y(s)=\frac{KG+K_dSG}{1+KG+K_dSG}S_p \\
e(s)=\frac{1}{1+KG+K_dSG}S_p$

where $K$, $K_d$ are propotional gain and derivative gain. $S$ is Lpalce variable. $S_p$ represents set point. $G$ is the plant. What I am interested in is the error behavior in time domain with respect to derivative gain $K_d$. Firstly for simplicity I assume my plant is perfect: $G=1$, so that

$e(s)=\frac{1}{1+K+K_dS}S_p$

By sinusoidal and periodic $Sp$, the error in time domain at steady status seems to be

$e(t)=A\vert|\frac{1}{1+K+K_dwj} \vert|\sin{\left(wt+\angle\frac{1}{1+K+K_dwj} \right)}$

where $A$ and $w$ are amplitude and frequency of the set point. In this expression both $K$ and $K_d$ have clear influence on the magnitude of the error. However when I tried simulation(on Simulink), the error influenced by $K_d$ barely nothing. I would expect the error behavior in time approaches to zero as $K_d$ increases or goes to $\infty$ per the exression of $e(t)$. However it is not. Is there any misktake in my derivation for $e(t)$?

Comment: what did the simulation do? step response? frequency sweep? ... at DC or low frequency, we can see that all the Kd terms go to 0, and error will be similar to P-control. (Not sure if this is what you are referring to in the question however, sorry if I misunderstood)

Comment: The set point of the close loop simulation is sinusoidal signal. I kind of understand at low frequency when $w$ is low, the influence of $K_d$ term could be minor such that the error behavior is similar to P control. What confuse me is, the derived expression shows error shall approach zero with sufficient $K_dw$ but I can not find that by making $K_dw$ large.

Comment: Hmm... I'd think that with  (Kd)(ω) ≫ (1+K)  you should be seeing it

Comment: @ Pete Thanks. I now can find the trend. What made difference is that I tried not to use the PID block in Simulink, but built the PID blocks based on definition. By that, the error in time shrinks with increasing $K_d$.